# How to make local SQL database in Java (.dat)?

Tags: java, sql, database, connection

I would like to ask how to create local database in .dat file with Java. There is a very easy method in Python with sqlite, which allows me to make connection with path to the .dat file and then commit queries and create tables etc, but I need to create database in Java now and I can't find an equivalent to this sqlite-method in Java. I tried to use:

java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("database.dat");

But with no result. Thank you.

Comment: See the set of tutorials at https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/ and at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm and https://www.javatpoint.com/java-sqlite

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally missed me.